# Why does my Theory unit test say "test has multiple result outcomes" in the test explorer summary?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

Normally, when I decorate an XUnit test method with `[Theory]` and use attributes like `[InlineData]` or `[ClassData]` to pass multiple sets of parameters into the test, the Visual Studio test explorer window lets me expand the test method to see each set of parameters as a test in its own right.

However, I have one test which is behaving differently - it shows as a single test in the tree view of projects, namespaces, classes, test methods etc, however in the test detail summary pane it says "Test has multiple result outcomes", which can be a mixture of passes and fails. This makes it more difficult to see exactly what has passed or failed, and also prevents me from debugging a test with just one set of parameters.

Here is my unit test:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using Xunit;

public class MyTestClass
{
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(MyTestData1))]
    public void MyTestMethod1(Color col, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        Assert.Equal(red, col.R);
        Assert.Equal(green, col.G);
        Assert.Equal(blue, col.B);
    }
}
```

The class supplying my test data:

```
public class MyTestData1 : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public MyTestData1()
    {
        this.Data = new List<object[]>();
        this.Data.Add(new object[] { Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0), 255, 0, 0 });
        this.Data.Add(new object[] { Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0), 0, 255, 0 });
        this.Data.Add(new object[] { Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255), 0, 0, 255 });
    }

    public List<object[]> Data { get; }
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() => this.Data.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Yes, it's a unit test for `System.Drawing.Color`, and I shouldn't need to write my own unit tests for that because it's maintained by Microsoft and so they're responsible for unit testing it. However it works nicely as a minimum reproducible example, as the fact that I'm using that particular struct in the parameters for my test seems to be the only difference between tests which behave as I'd expect in the test explorer and tests which don't. In the actual project where I hit this issue I'm using arrays of `Color` as parameters, but the issue seems to be the same.

What do I need to do to allow me to expand this test in the test explorer, so that I can run/debug it with just one of the sets of parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I worked it out, but it wasn't easy finding the correct search terms, so I'm asking and answering the question in the hope that it'll be easier to find for the next person who comes across this odd behaviour.

The breakthrough was when I found this GitHub issue [Question: Why do some theories get expanded into individual test cases and others not? #1473](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1473)

> In the Visual Studio test runner, test cases are discovered in one process, and executed in another. Therefore, test cases must be able to be turned into an unqualified string representation (aka, "serialized") in order to be run. We can also serialize at the test method level, because that just involves knowing the type and method name (both strings). When you start putting data into the mix, we need to ensure we know how to serialize that data; if we can't serialize all of the data for a theory, then we have to fall back to just a single method (which we know we can serialize).

So yes, the problem is my usage of `System.Drawing.Color` as a parameter for the test, because `System.Drawing.Color` isn't serializable, so Xunit can't provide enough information about my test cases to the test explorer for the test explorer to display them the way I'm expecting. So I need to use some type other than `System.Drawing.Color`.

Because the only thing I'm using the `Color` struct for is a container to hold the red, green and blue components of a colour, I could use 3 `int` or `byte` parameters to represent those components, but I'd rather not go down that route, particularly as I'm working with arrays of colours, I'd like to keep all 3 components of one colour together in a single object, and I'd like my code to be as readable as possible, particularly with respect to the fact that those 3 numbers between them represent a colour.

The solution which worked for me in this case was to create my own class which implements just enough of what `System.Drawing.Color` does to meet the needs of my tests, but which also implements `IXunitSerializable` so that Xunit knows how to serialize it.

```
public class Colour : IXunitSerializable
{
    public byte R { get; set; }
    public byte G { get; set; }
    public byte B { get; set; }

    public static Colour FromArgb(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        return new Colour { R = r, G = g, B = b };
    }

    public static Colour FromArgb(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        return new Colour
        {
            R = (byte)r,
            G = (byte)g,
            B = (byte)b,
        };
    }

    public void Deserialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        this.R = info.GetValue<byte>(nameof(this.R));
        this.G = info.GetValue<byte>(nameof(this.G));
        this.B = info.GetValue<byte>(nameof(this.B));
    }

    public void Serialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.R), this.R);
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.G), this.G);
        info.AddValue(nameof(this.B), this.B);
    }
}
```

When I changed my unit test and test data class to use this `Colour` class instead of `System.Drawing.Color`, everything worked as I expected, including being able to expand the test in the test explorer so that I can run it with just one of the sets of parameters supplied from the test data class.

The important parts of this `Colour` class are the `Serialize` method (create a plain-text representation of the object) and `Deserialize` method (create an instance of the object from its plain-text representation).

In the `Serialize` method, we want to store the properties of the current `Colour` instance which are necessary to re-create an identical instance of `Colour`. We do this by passing a key (the name of the property) and a value (the value of the property) to the `IXunitSerializationInfo` instance's `AddValue` method.

In the `Deserialize` method, we're running in the context of an instance of the `Colour` class whose parameterless constructor has been called, but nothing else has been set. So we need to set the properties of the current instance to values that we can get from the supplied `IXunitSerializationInfo` object by passing the key for each property (in this case its property name) to the `GetValue` method.

You could use any string as the key in the calls to `GetValue` and `AddValue`, as long as you use the same string when saving and when getting the same property. For this reason, it's simpler in my mind just to use the name of the property as the key.